# Pros and cons of "%{HTTPS} off" vs "%{SERVER_PORT} 80" in .htaccess RewriteCond for redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To route traffic to `https://example.com`... what's are the pros and cons of these two approaches?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,QSA]
```

vs.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,QSA]
```

Also, is there any effective difference between `(.*)` and `^(.*)$` in the RewriteRule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* difference between those two rule blocks is the first condition:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
> ```

vs

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 [OR]
> ```

The first condition checks whether HTTPS is `off` (regardless of server port) and the second condition specifically checks the server port that the request is being made to. Port 80 is the *default* port for HTTP (ie. not HTTPS).

So, if you are serving HTTP over the default port then there is effectively  no difference between those two conditions. If you are not serving HTTP over the default port then the first condition will still work (as this is derived by the server), however, the second condition would need to be modified to the appropriate port number.

> Also, is there any effective difference between `(.*)` and `^(.*)$` in the `RewriteRule`?

No difference, since regex is *greedy* by default and the `*` quantifier will consume as much of the string (URL-path in this case) as possible. The reason you see `^(.*)$` a lot in the wild is just personal preference or blind copy/pasting.

However, in this case the surrounding parentheses are also unnecessary, since you are not making use of the captured backreference (ie. `$1`). You just need `.*` - although even that is not optimal since it unnecessarily traverses the entire URL-path. You don't need to match anything, you just need the rule to be successful. ie. `^` or `.?` or `$` would suffice and be more efficient.

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,QSA]
> ```

The `QSA` flag is entirely redundant here since the query string is passed through by default.

Comment: What a clear and detailed answer! Thank you so much!